# My for loop is not producing what i am expecting.

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

The way this should run is a color image changing. The image change would be the position in the array.  This would look like a sort of a animated .gif repeating itself for ever.

```
<script>
var images = new Array(4);

images[0] = new Image(50, 50);
images[0].src = "0.gif";
images[1] = new Image(50, 50);
images[1].src = "1.gif";
images[2] = new Image(50, 50);
images[2].src = "2.gif";
images[3] = new Image(50, 50);
images[3].src = "3.gif";
images[4] = new Image(50, 50);

for(time=0; time>4; time++){
document.View.src = images[time]
}
```

```
<body>
<img src = "0.gif" name = "View" height = 50 width = 50>
</body>
```

Clearly I have done some thing wrong because all I get is the first image in the array and it never changes. I am new to javascript, so any help I would be grateful.

Comment: I corrected the Less-than sign problem yet it still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
for (time = 0; time < 4; time++) {
```

You had `time > 4`, but your initial value is 0, so your condition is false to begin with.  The body of the for loop never runs, so the image never changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just some comments…

```
> var images = new Array(4);
```

You initialise the array with length 4, then add 5 members so the length is 5 (items 0 to 4). Don't bother setting a length, just initialise the array using a literal:

```
var images = [];
```

Also, there is a `document.images` collection that is all the img elements in the document, so likely not a good idea to have a global variable with the same name. Perhaps `imgArray` would be a better name.

```
> document.View.src
```

Accessing elements using their name as a property of the document object is a non–standarised feature that should not be used. HTML5 removes *name* from the img attribute list, but retains it when discussing collections (perhaps we should just go back to HTML 4.01 and DOM 3).

You can instead use the images collection:

```
document.images.View.src
```

or if you're game, the HTML5 [`HTMLAllCollection`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-dom-interfaces.html#htmlallcollection-0)